# Get <a> content via Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get a content of `<a>` element via `Nokogiri` by doing the following:

```
novelty.title = page.at_css('h1 a')
```

It saving to database like this: `<a href="a_link_to_a_novelty_title">A title</a>`. So, how can I get only `A title` from the `<a>` tag? Thanks.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about a problem you're having with code we need the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem, along with the minimum input data used to demonstrate the problem, and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write as below to get the text.

```
ovelty.title = page.at_css('h1 a').text
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped.